# Leshev baSukkah without eating bread

Tags: halacha, sukkot

Is there an halachic possibility of saying Leshev baSukkah for someone who cannot eat bread (or anything HaMotzi)?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20604/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/103372/759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mishnah Berurah 639:48](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.639.48?lang=he)

> והמתענה בסוכות או שאין דעתו לאכול פת באותו יום אז לכו"ע כל אימת שיצא יציאה גמורה חייב לברך
>
> Regarding someone who is fasting on *sukkot* or who does not intend to eat bread that day, according to all opinions whenever he leaves [the *sukkah*] for an extended period of time [and then returns to the *sukkah*], he must make the *berachah* [of *leshev basukkah*].

Comment: Note other disagree so, as usual, nothing is actually "according to all opinions"